# Google Spreadsheet Separating Rows By Names

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to follow my own mutual fund purchases and trying to input the results into a spreadsheet to calculate the XIRR (internal rate of return). I am planning on entering my data for every purchase I make and will have a table as follows;

`Fund Name           Fund Date            Purchase
TD Balanced         November 30, 2015    900
Scotia Balanced     November 24, 2015    1000
Scotia Balanced     November 03, 2015    5000
Scotia Balanced     June    23, 2015     -2000
Scotia Balanced     April   02, 2015     4000
TD Balanced         January 04, 2015     4000
Scotia Balanced     July    20, 2014     800
Scotia Balanced     March   02, 2014     400
TD Balanced         January 29, 2014     10000`

I want to then be able to create multiple small tables from the data above as follows;

`Fund Name           Fund Date            Purchase
Scotia Balanced     November 24, 2015    1000
Scotia Balanced     November 03, 2015    5000
Scotia Balanced     June    23, 2015     -2000
Scotia Balanced     April   02, 2015     4000
Scotia Balanced     July    20, 2014     800
Scotia Balanced     March   02, 2014     400`


`Fund Name           Fund Date            Purchase
TD Balanced         November 30, 2015    900
TD Balanced         January 04, 2015     4000
TD Balanced         January 29, 2014     10000`

I have tried pivot tables which can do this, however I am unable to calculate the XIRR properly with pivot tables. Any help would be appreciated it please.

Future Steps: Ideally I would want to create this in such a way that I can add all my purchases to table 1. If the result is a new fund it will automatically create a separate table. I would want each of the tables to have there own XIRR calculation with a total XIRR calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
=query(A:C,"select * where A <>'' order by A asc")
```

might help but you are not going to obtain XIRR from details of purchases only.